# Ubuntu 13.04 vs Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.04

If I install 13.10 on my system, is there a security risk If I don't upgrade after two years?

Also, if I don't mind upgrading every two years, is recommended that I get 13.10?

Thank you!

Comment: 13.04 is now more of a security risk, as it just become [End Of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 8):

Both Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 are (or will be) [short term releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), which are supported for only **9 months**. You should use these releases if you want the newest versions of software and are prepared to upgrade regularly. 13.10 is still considered a pre-release **alpha** version and should only be used if you like getting your hands dirty.

If you do not want to upgrade regularly, use the *Long Term Support* release, currently 12.04. This is supported for **5 years** after release. (The upcoming 14.04 will also presumably be an LTS release).

An out-of-support release receives no updates, so security problems found and patched in later versions are not fixed. That is not to say that it instantly becomes unsafe to use, since there are relatively few threats targetting desktop linux of any flavour, but it would be unwise to use an obsolete version for either running servers or browsing the web, since these are the most likely attack vectors.

(Note that short term releases before 13.04 received 18 months support instead of 9).

Comment: i don't follow up on ubuntu for some time, and i was under the wrong impression all 04 were LTS. thanks for reminding me it aint so!